# Книги по С/С++

Tags: c++, c, книги

Уже около года работаю программистом, сейчас работаю с PHP и C#, в данный момент заинтересовался С++, встал вопрос выбора литературы. Посмотрел Страуструпа и Шилдта, и там и там подразумевается что читающий уже знает С. Собственно вопрос: можно ли имея кое какие знания в программировании изучать С++ не зная С, а если нет может ли кто-нибудь посоветовать книги по С++ с нуля, либо книги по чистому С.

Comment: Изучать можно, но в результате все равно придется изучить С :). Я бы, рекомендовал такого автора как Лафоре.

Comment: Нашёл "Р. Лафоре - Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++", Вы эту книгу имели ввиду? И если всё равно придётся изучать С, не можете подсказать книги по нему?

Comment: Да именном эта.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я поддержу **Mirdin**'а, для вас отличным выбором будет
Р. Лафоре - "Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++".

Хоть в ней и даются не слишком большие знания по каждой из тем отдельно, но количество этих тем очень велико: STL, шаблоны, исключения. Она для вас станет отличным путеводителем по миру C++.

Ну а потом обязательным к прочтению будет Александреску, Страуструп и что-нибудь про STL("STL Для профессионалов" -- отличный выбор)

Comment: Александреску- уже в самом конце, после Медвежонка, STL, Шаблонов Джосаттиса, книжек Мейерса и пр.

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, посмотрел Лафоре, действительно объёмно, пролистал пару глав - изложение материала понравилось. Думаю на ней и остановлюсь. Страуструпа купил уже в печатном варианте.

Answer (score 5):

Если хотите хорошо подтянуть С - самая лучшая книга - С.Прата http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4195165  , у него же есть по C++ но о ней ничего не могу сказать . Крайне доступно разъясняет, поэтому не будет проблем читать в оригинале даже если у Вас не сильно продвинутое знание английского. Если есть возможность и желание - возьмите в бумаге, но насколько я знаю она уже много лет у нас не печатается и ее тяжело найти

Answer (score 3):

[@Mr_OST](/users/3744/mr_ost), думаю без прочтения K&R (Язык программирования Си. Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи.) и написания нескольких десятков программок, Вам не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

C тебе незачем. Не надо его изучать. Начинай сразу с С++. Поможет тебе в этом Дейтел - как программировать на С++. Учит с нуля и толково! С первого раза поймешь

Comment: Не согласен. 
Я тоже сразу начал изучать C++ по Шилдту.
Там разбирались лишь базовые возможности Cи типа printf time.
А в реальности большинство библиотек написано на Си, что затрудняет их понимание.

Comment: Дейтел, в принципе хороший учебник, но это учебник, он требует наличия преподавателя.

Comment: Я без препода мог нормально изучать

Comment: @navi1893, оно и заметно по вопросам.

Comment: Если я задаю вопросы, значит у меня есть желание изучать и я что то делаю. Не думаю что ты @mikillskegg сразу стал знатоком, когда начинал

Comment: @navi1893, дело не в количестве, а в качестве. Вы беретесь за довольно сложные вещи (тот же OPN каклькулятор), не понимая простых (передача аргументов в функции, например). Для вас полезно было бы как раз начать с самоучителя по Си, пройти его от начала до конца, заодно познакомиться с реализацией основных алгоритмов, а потом уже применять полученные знания в программировании C++.

Comment: Это все домашняя работа, на оценку. У меня нет выбора. Я не виноват что у нас в универе так тупо проходят

Comment: @navi1893, при чем здесь универ? Для диплома (чтобы экзамен сдать) *изучать* язык дело пустое.

Если хотите *действительно разбираться* в программировании, то знание Си (и много самостоятельно написанных на нем программ) необходимо.

Comment: @navi1893, я не понял, так ты сам С++ изучаешь или в универе?

Comment: в универе ради галочки проходят. Просто задаем вопросы и на них отвечают как могут. А так сам дома копаюсь, ищу, спрашиваю и учу @mikillskegg

Comment: @navi1893, а попробуйте почитать что-нибудь не только по конкретному C/C++. Я вот вспомнил, что давным-давно читал книгу 

    Пратт Т. Языки программирования. Разработка и реализация 

и она мне мого дала. Наверное не меньше, чем Кнут. Сейчас посмотрел в гугле - и надо же - продают и сейчас (уже 4-е издание).

Еще есть хорошая книжка: 

    Практика программирования Брайан Керниган, Роб Пайк 

там примеры интересные (насколько помню, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

Четко и как надо пишется у Страуструпа в книге "Принципы и практика использования С++". Как раз для начинающих рассчитана и будет интересна и для профессионалов.