# Насколько надо изучающему C++ знать C. Лучший учебник по C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, книги

Вопрос особенно к мэтрам как @Котик @avp  @mikillskegg @ling @cy6erGn0m
Почитал (пару глав) книгу Стивен Парта Язык программирования C++, но, как понял, там очень мало полезного. В частности там рассказывается о "строках - массивах символов" а это по моему С? Я слышал, что в C++ есть класс string с методами. И ещё много таких примеров а мне кажется, что в книге в основном  рассматриваются не совсем новые методы программирования (например, "Язык С++ унаследовал от С удобный пакет функций, работающих с символами"). Действительно, в C++ не так много нового по сравнению с C и всё так "Объектно Ориентированно". Полистал также "Д.Керниган Д.Ритчи Язык программирования C", но она показалась "Слегка устаревшей".
Собственно вопросы:

1. Насколько надо знать C чтобы лучше понять C++?
2. Какую книгу посоветуете по C++, где упор делается на современное ООП программирование на C++ и почти сразу описание чего-то типа "Стандартной библиотеки C++" как это в книге по C?
3. Насколько нужно знать C чтоб понять C++?
4. Насколько различаются C++ и Visual C++ и поддерживаются ли во втором например функции/методы первого?
5. Слышал про библиотеки типа "QT", можно ли зная их сделать то же что и в VC++?

Comment: Мне книгу в которой описывается как можно больше современных стандартных объектов C++. Но при этом основательно описывается современный синтаксис C++. Как вы изучили C++?

Comment: не путайте объекты и классы.

Comment: О, меня мэтром уже назвали.

Comment: Пратта - прекрасный учебник. Читай до конца. Там дальше и про std::string, и про STL будет рассказано. А часть, унаследованную от С, тоже знать надо. Если найдешь книжку того же Праты по С (она давно не переиздавалась и в инете ее тоже почему-то нет), то очень рекомендую почитать. K&R - классика, но с нее лучше не начинать.

Comment: А как насчёт Гербельт Шильдт полный справочник по C++ (там содержание и название многообещающее..)?

Comment: Кернигана/Ритчи - зря вы недооцениваете. Это наше (вернее ваше ) всё должно быть.

Comment: К&R на завтрак, Страуструп в обед, TAOCP закусить вечерком. Полгода такой диеты и юный падаван волшебным образом превращается в матерого джедая.
P.S. Навряд ли K&R устарела. Ядра windows/linux и quake3 написаны на С. Даже чтобы почитать этот сайт вы вынуждены неявно запускать код написанный на С.

Comment: 1) Как говорил создатель С++ С++ это С с классами.

Comment: @Rules: по поводу Герберта Шильдта есть [вот такое мнение](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/B/bullschildt.html).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 9):

Хотя я в **метры** не попал:), но напишу.

1) Есть мнение, что знание С даже вредит глубокому изучению. Но С можно изучить за 21 день поверхностно, но вот плюсы - вряд ли.

2) Практика. Практика и ещё раз практика. Можно долго читать книги, но безрезультатно. Если хочется стандартную библиотеку узнать - то читать наверно стоит первоисточники - Степанова.

3) "что бы понять рекурсию, нужно понять рекурсию":). Что бы понять с++ нужно понять с++. Или это перефразированный первый вопрос.

4) С++ - это название языка и его спецификация. Visual C++ это реализация его от МС. Ещё к примеру есть gcc, clang и некоторые другие. Это как спросить, чем гоночная машина отличается от болида мерседеса.

5) а погуглите. qt - конкретный фреймворк. VC++ - среда разработки. Смотрите предыдущий вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Пожалуй присоединюсь к [[@gecube](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube). Ничего развернуто писать не хочу, т.к. C++ не люблю, но  противопоставлять его Си не хочу.

[[[[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules), IMHO  знать Си (и уметь им пользоваться) надо. Я имею в виду не набор функций libc (найдете библиотеку получше - используйте ее или напишите свою), а в основном работу с указателями. Надо хорошо разобраться с распределением памяти, работой со стеком, обработкой сигналов, списками аргументов функций.   Иначе понимания "как это на самом деле происходит" (в смысле перелопачивания железом битиков) у Вас не будет. И естественно, системные вызовы (я имею в виду *nix), хотя к языку это почти не относится.

Кстати, читал недавно интересный сборник интервью (десятка два, примерно 2007 года, называется "Пионеры программирования") с создателями популярных языков. Интересно, что Страуструп там довольно сдержано говорит об ООП (видимо и в его глазах эта парадигма так и не стала "серебяной пулей"), а позиционирует С++, как "мультипарадигменный" язык с уклоном в системное программирование. И использование STL он не считает применением ООП.

Еще там было любопытное высказывания Кернигана (в интервью про AWK), что С++ сложен и огромен и трудно понимать чужие программы, написанные на нем (и еще он упомянул тут же perl), а вот программы на Си просты и понятны. Вот это мне запомнилось, наверное просто совпадает с моими представлениями.

А вообще, [[[[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules) - лишних знаний не бывает. Лучше всего любую задачу решать на наиболее подходящем языке (из тех, конечно, какими хорошо владеешь).

Comment: Указатели, стек, сигналы,... а причем тут C? Я изучаю указатели используя всю мощь С++. Такое ощущение, что в С++ нет ни стека ни сигналов.

Comment: @mikelsv В С++ базовая работа с указателями такая же как в Си. НО! Появляется куча моментов. Во-первых, никто голые указатели в С++ не использует. А используются т.н. "умные" указатели, которые сами следят за использованием ресурсов и занимаются управлением памятью. Во-вторых, в С++ есть много наворотов вроде перезагрузки операторов. В результате полной уверенности что происходит нет без полного анализа включаемого кода =( Далее. В С++ стек тоже есть. Но его работу проще проанализировать на примере Си.

Comment: @mikelsv, сигналов в Си (как языке) правда нет. Я имел в виду особенности программирования *действительно* асинхронных функций, т.е. функций время вызова которых никак не контролируется ни компилятором, ни библиотеками.

@gecube, если отбросить примеры из учебников, то IMHO частота использования "голых" указателей в С++ программах будет побольше, чем "умных". 

Где-то я вообще видел информацию, что  большинство С++ программ на самом деле являются Си программами в которых вместо printf пишут `<<` (и т.п.).

Answer (score 5):

Можно, нельзя... После С, до С... Возьми и поучи и то, и другое. 100% не прогадаешь.

> Слышал про библиотеки типа "QT", можно ли зная их сделать то же что и в VC++?

И даже больше. С помощью  Qt4 можно делать потрясающие интерфейсы. Кроме того, она поставляет кучу полезных библиотек для многопоточного программирования, работ с сетью, с базами данных, с файловой системой. А ее QString - просто потрясающая штука.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос сложен и многогранен.

1. Лучше начать изучение с Си. Т.к. он существенно проще. В программе мероприятий - ознакомление со стандартной библиотекой Си, синтаксисом языка и реализацией базовых алгоритмов. Это позволит понять как это работает.
2. Далее нужно изучить отличия С++ от С. И запомнить их на зубок. Дело в том, что зачастую С++ и С компиляторы - практически одно и то же. Все-таки С++ вырос из Си. И поэтому можнр писать на С++ в стиле Си. Иногда это может быть оправданно, например, ради эффективности по какому-нибудь из критериев, но с другой стороны писать на С++ в стиле Си - скорее всего будет дурным тоном. Но чтобы понимать что можно, а что нельзя нужно знать оба языка. В крайнем случае, никто не мешает использовать С++ как С с классами
3. Обязательно нужно освоить инструментарий. Это компиляторы от Борланда до Ваткома, включая оптимизирующий компилятор от Интела, инструментальные среды, отладчики. Также стоит изучить работу хотя бы с несколькими библиотеками вроде MFC и Qt. Опять же, время потраченное на это не пропадет, т.к. позволит при решении задачи выбрать конкретные языковые средства и конкретные инструменты.

Comment: Вспоминая Шерлока Холмса. Зачем вам порой бесполезные знания отличия С от С++, тем более на зубок?
Инструментарий освоить нужно, но не весь же. Достаточно найти подходящие и эффективные. Хотя тут я может не особо прав.
А насчет С и простых примеров, так их можно изучать и в С++, и не упираясь в потолок С сразу пойти в чудесный мир С++.

Comment: Дело в том, что программист все равно в С++ столкнется с наследием Си. Или в виде вызовов библиотеки Си, или при межмодульном взаимодействии (вспоминаем, что у Си вполне ясный и конкретный ABI, в отличии от С++), или просто будет старый код... И нужно знать не только как нужно делать, но и как делать не стоит.

Comment: @gecude что за  ABI??? поясни в двух словах или дай ссылку (желательно на рус)

Comment: http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 2):

Пытаться изучать С++ без знания С - все равно что пытаться овладеть математикой без знания арифметики. Так что половина заданных вопросов некорректна.

Из С важно вынести (в смысле понять) пойнтерную арифметику и управление памятью.

Answer (score 1):

1. Совсем необязательно знать С. Это два разных языка хоть и похожи синтаксически.
2. Книга С.Прата офигенна, чувак. Лучшее что я читал. Ну и философия С++ Б.Эккеля
3. Тебе нужна практика. В языке много тонкостей которые можно понять только путем проб и ошибок.
4. По идее VC++ не должен сильно отличаться от стандарта С++. Это просто среда разработки+библиотеки и фреймворки.
5. Смотря что тебе требуется. Каждый из этих инструментов заточен под что-то свое, но в общем и целом они универсальны. Qt для тех кому нужна кроссплатформенность.

Answer (score 0):

1. Си можно не знать вообще. Мозг не будет цепляться за сишные идеи.
2. Я прочитал только одну книгу по C++. И то случайно.
3. С++ можно не знать, но понимать стоит обязательно.
4. С++ он и в Visual С++. Для меня он вообще один. Компиляторы чуток разные, да.
5. Да все можно, если заняться.

Comment: По п.4 - каждая версия компилятора отличается. Помню как мучался при переводе проекта с vs6.0 на vs2010... Вроде бы язык тот же, а вроде бы с полтычка проект не собирается. Править пришлось много где. Ну, или разница между g++ и borland. Просто жуть.Писали с сестрой ее проект курсовой, ну, и черт дернул использовать c++0x. Результат-в колледже борланд код не съел, пришлось даунгрейдиться до предыдущей версии стандарта, при этом эти идиоты не сообразили, что низзя в колледже ставить пиратский борланд. Лучше бы опен-сурсным вещам учили: зачем людей привязывать к конкретной, не лучшей реализации

Comment: @gecube, известная проблема. Недавно на глаза попалась своя прога года 95-го. Так вся в ифдефах, чтобы K&R cc компилил (в HP-UX очень долго только он стандартно с машиной поставлялся).

Comment: @gecube, а я о чем. Компиляторы разные, подогнать код с vs6 под vs2003, потом под vs2005 и g++ стоило кучу сил. Сейчас мой код под все собирается, кроме vs6 которую я уже сто лет не видел. В борланд я слава богу не совался. Вот так, компиляторы разные, а С++ для меня один.

Comment: @mikelsv Ну, так как у Вас получается, что С++ везде С++? Все-таки получается, что он везде разный (свой). И эти нюансы нужно иметь в виду.

Comment: C++ в VC++ - иногда ощущение, что другой язык. А борланд часто идет еще дальше.

Comment: @gecube, C++ и PHP разные языки. А С++ везде одинаковый. Нюансы в компиляторах. В одном область видимости по другому сделана, в другом friends нужно правильно прописать иначе будет ругаться. Еще помнится memcpy() в винде аналог memmove(). Остальные уже не помню. Если писать в соответствии со стандартом эти проблемы вылезать не будут.

Comment: @mikelsv Будут. Хотя бы по той причине, что каждый компилятор поддерживает какие-то определенные версии стандарта. g++, например, в этом отношении лучше, чем msvc, а тем более лучше, чем borland. Я уж не говорю, что разные команды разработчиков компилятор по разному эти стандарты трактуют...

Answer (score 0):

Полностью согласен с Mr_OST - нужно рассматривать C и C++ как разные языки, потом будете лишней работой заниматься. Если вам нужно учить С, то учите С, если нужно С++ - то учите С++.

В С используется printf/scanf, в С++ программах используются cout/cin
В С используется #define, в С++ - const type name;
В С управление памятью выполняется с помощью alloc/afree, в С++ new/delete.

Таких сравнений можно привести большое колличество. Советую почитать в википедии раздел различия С++ от С: [Отличия С++ от C](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.A1.2B.2B_.D0.BE.D1.82_C).

Особенно примечателен раздел:

> C++ не включает в себя C
>
> Несмотря на то, что большая часть кода
> C будет справедлива и для C++, C++ не
> является надмножеством C и не включает
> его в себя. Существует и такой верный
> для C код, который неверен для C++.
> Это отличает его от Objective C, ещё
> одного усовершенствования C для ООП,
> как раз являющегося надмножеством C.
>
> Существуют и другие различия.
> Например, C++ не разрешает вызывать
> функцию main() внутри программы, в то
> время как в C это действие правомерно.
> Кроме того, C++ более строг в
> некоторых вопросах; например, он не
> допускает неявное приведение типов
> между несвязанными типами указателей и
> не разрешает использовать функции,
> которые ещё не объявлены.
>
> Более того, код, верный для обоих
> языков, может давать разные результаты
> в зависимости от того, компилятором
> какого языка он оттранслирован.
> Например, на большинстве платформ
> следующая программа печатает «С», если
> компилируется компилятором C, и «C++»
> — если компилятором C++. Так
> происходит из-за того, что символьные
> константы в C (например, 'a') имеют
> тип int, а в C++ — тип char, а размеры
> этих типов обычно различаются.
>
> <pre><code>#include <stdio.h>   int main() {
>     printf("%s\n", (sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)) ? "C++" : "C");
>     return 0; }</code></pre>

Если хотите изучить С++ без С, то советую почитать следующие книги:

1. т.2 Э. Кёниг, Б. My Эффективное
       программирование на C++ Серия C++
       In-Depth
2. Язык программирования С++. Вводный
       курс. 5-е изд (новое издание,
       описывает С++11)
3. Солтер Николас А. и др. - С++ для
       профессионалов - 2006 (на английском
       языке есть новая версия, описывающая
       C++11 [Professional C++, 2nd
       Edition](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-C-2nd-Edition.productCd-0470932449,descCd-tableOfContents.html))

По STL могу посоветовать следующие книги:

1. [C++ и STL: справочное руководство,
       2-е издание (серия C++ in Depth)](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1665-5.html)
2. [C++ Standard Library, The: A
       Tutorial and Reference, 2nd
       Edition](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-standard-library-a-tutorial-and-reference-9780321623218) (данная книга должна
       выйти в 2013 году на русском языке в
       издательстве williamspublishing)
3. [Параллельное программирование на
       С++ в действии](http://дмк.рф/catalog/computer/programming/c/978-5-94074-448-1/)

Еще дополнительно советую почитать книгу
[Алгоритмы на C++. Фундаментальные алгоритмы и структуры данных.](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1650-1.html)

Comment: > В С используется printf/scanf, в С++ программах используются cout/cin В С используется #define, в С++ - const type name; В С управление памятью выполняется с помощью alloc/afree, в С++ new/delete.

Не согласен.

1. это частное мнение
2. С++ позволяет использовать и С-способ, и С++ способ. Нет жесткого ограничения не использовать `printf` или `scanf`.
3. Кстати говоря, многие задачи удобнее решать `printf`/`scanf`, чем с помощью `stdin`/`stdout`. Аналогично с парами `sprintf`/`sscanf` vs `stringstream` vs `strstream`

Comment: По списку рекомендованной литературы могу поставить плюс. По осальному - минус. Отношения между С и С++ неоднозначны и сложны и говорить однозначно, что С - это просто подмножество С++ или что это разные языки - неправильно. Несмотря на нюансы (с большинством из которых приходиться очень редко встречаться), все-так С++ - это надстройка над С. С лежит в основе С++. Сам я лично пришел к С++ из многолетнего программирования на С и считаю это большим плюсом, потому что опыт низкоуровневого программирования был мне очень полезен.

Comment: >Кстати говоря, многие задачи удобнее решать printf/scanf, чем с помощью stdin/stdout. Аналогично с парами sprintf/sscanf vs stringstream

Возможно некоторые задачи проще выполнять с помощью printf/scanf, но в большинстве случаев хватает cin/cout, тем более не надо мучиться с запоминанием бесчисленного количества ключей (%d,%s) - задал не тот ключ, а потом ищешь ошибку несколько дней. Плюс к тому же имеется удобная работа с классами (можно перегрузить операторы '<<' и '>>' и т.д.).

Comment: 1. Как раз ключи scanf/printf лаконичнее чем модификаторы для cout/cin

2. У оператора << не совсем очевидный приоритет, что может давать странные результаты в случае вызовов ф-ций и вычислений при написании вывода в одну строчку.

3. Соглашусь, что cout/cin может быть удобно использовать со своими классами.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Koval, возможность перегрузки операторов (да и методов) это  плюс или минус - **большой вопрос**.

Если цель разработки - создание проблемно-ориентированного "языка" (среды программирования), то наверное плюс. Другой вопрос, как быстро можно научиться ее хорошо использовать.

Если Вам надо модифицировать/доотладить **большую чужую** программу, то для Вас такие вещи, сделанные (и обычно не документированные) другим программистом - явный минус.

Comment: @avp
тут уже проблема не в перегрузке а в хреновом программисте который не вёл документацию...

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял ответ на мой вопрос очень сложен и многогранен и чтобы не создавать полный хаос и холивар я учту мнения всех участвующих в вопросе оставлю его чтобы задающиеся тем же вопросом что и я могли посмотреть ответы на него и приму свой ответ т.к. не могу точно определиться чей ответ лучше/хуже всех... Всем участвующим спасибо. Я думаю что этот вопрос не когда не будет закрыт для обсуждений но по правилам Хешкод я всё таки должен закрыть его...

Answer (score -2):

Джесс Либерти: Освой самостоятельно C++ за 21 день. лутше 5ое издание купить. В интернете есть только 3е. Знатоки С++ советуют: С++ изучается без знаний языка С, если язык С уже знаете то надо просто перешагнуть через него на С++. QT своими возможностями обгоняет MFC как мне кажется.

Comment: > Знатоки С++ советуют

Хотелось бы послушать самих знатоков, или хотя бы увидеть ссылки на авторитетные источники.

> С++ изучается без знаний языка С

Очень спорно. Если не умея алгоритмически выражать свои мысли, начать изучать ООП, ничего хорошего не получится. А алгоритмы можно изучать и на Си.

Comment: Авторы вышеуказанной книги советуют, да и от других людей слышал. А С++ не только ООП а также классическое функциональное программирование. Алгоритмы можно изучать и "учя" С++, так зачем время тратить на устаревшие функции языка С (например кому в голову взбредет на С++ выделять динамическую память как на языке С и тп). Поддержку С в С++ добавили только потому что много кода на нем написано то бишь для совместимости и только.

Comment: > А С++ не только ООП а также классическое функциональное программирование.

Можешь ещё добавить метапрограммирование. (на шаблонах) В нём есть всё, но в итоге -- ничего. Нельзя так бездумно смешивать парадигмы.

Comment: >Поддержку С в С++ добавили

ну это мягко говоря неверно. Она там была изначально.

Comment: Добавили при создании языка

Comment: > Поддержку С в С++ добавили

Скорее уж наоборот, в Си добавили поддержку ООП и получился С++ :)

Comment: с++ проектировали с учетом багажа кода написанного на С.
Первые компиляторы С++ - это препроцессор + компилятор на С. Такой даже сейчас существует. Называется [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/).

Comment: вот по этому и существует как  Comeau. видимо ))

Comment: Не обижайте комму - это один из лучших компиляторов.

Comment: да я не обижаю. просто все компиляторы С++ поддерживают ассемблерные вставки это же не значит что нужно учить ассемблер чтобы знать С++. а вообще я признаю язык С++ принятый в 79 году. то бишь С++ STANDART

Comment: c++ 79 года??? да ещё и стандарт??? (для тех кто в танке - с++ появился в 1983)

Comment: 79? C++?

может в 99?

Comment: @котик, а как насчет моего вопроса?

Comment: @котик, куда же вы удалили так быстро коммент!?, я ведь увидел что вы здесь были...! :)

Comment: @Rules Да там коммент глупый был, поскольку понятно, что @perfect опечатался :)

Comment: @Котик а что по поводу моего вопроса, выскажите свое мнение пожалуйста какую книгу или последовательность каких книг лучше по вашему мнению прочитать для основательного освоения C++?  
Как Вы освоили C++ ?

Comment: @Rules Мое мнение по этому вопросу я когда-то озвучил [здесь.](http://hashcode.ru/questions/49479/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c)

Comment: @Котик, а  C++ Primer == Стивен парта язык программирования C++ ?

Answer (score -2):

Недавно сам задавал похожий вопрос:

[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/156202/c-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D1%81)

Одна из рекомендаций была книга:
Р. Лафоре - "Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++

Сейчас читаю, книгой доволен. Ориентированна как раз на ООП + описан STL и ещё много чего. В общем рекомендую.

По поводу надо ли знать С:

Выслушав множество мнений пришёл к выводу что С знать не обязательно, и даже вредно. Если учить С то только как отдельный язык.